# Email triggered from Elastic Cloud watcher including additional text in email html body

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elastic-cloud

I am using elastic cloud (Elastic Search : v8.6.2) and have configured watchers to trigger email for elastic search query which fetched results from specific index pattern(Which has server logs). Below email action I have configured in my watcher.

```
"actions": {
"send_email": {
  "email": {
    "profile": "standard",
    "to": [
      "toemail@domain.com"
    ],
    "subject": "LogMonitor - Identified keyword matched {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} times",
    "body": {
      "html": "The following {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} text matched<table border=1><tr><td>Message</td></tr>{{#ctx.payload.hits.hits}}<tr><td>{{_source.message}}</td></tr>{{/ctx.payload.hits.hits}}</table>"
    }
  }
}}
```

Below is the sample message which I have received in email which is appending **"http://"** before the java class name and it is visible as a link in email. 
http://SampleClass.java:193 hello this is a test

Actual Message should sent in email like below as simple message 
SampleClass.java:193 hello this is a test

I have tried disabling html sanitization from elastic search user setting in Elastic Cloud Admin Panel but it didn't work.

> xpack.notification.email.html.sanitization.enabled: false

Can anyone know what I missed in configuration part or in watcher to get actual log message which is indexed.

Thanks in advance.